# Predict Similar Suppliers in the supplier/Trader list using pattern matching in SQL

Tags: sql-server, pattern-matching, string-matching, similarity, soundex

Help required at your earliest guys!

I have duplicate records for consignor name who trade with us... I want to search similar consignor names that are entered misspelled or have entered wrongly in the system.

For example parameter : ABC trader

The query I need to return:

```
 1. ABC   , karachi , pakistan 
 2. ABCA  , karachi , Pakistan 
 3. ABCA trader,karachi, Pakistan 
 4. AABC trd, karachi , pakistan
```

I want to write the query that returns very much similar names to the entered data..

This is sample query assumption data set is :

```
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ii.Consignor_Name ASC) AS rn,
       ii.ConsignorName     AS cn,
       ii.ConsignorAddress  AS ca,
       rc.CountryName       AS cc

FROM   Index AS ii WITH(NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN Countries AS rc WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  ii.Consignor_CountryName = rc.CountryID
WHERE  YEAR(ii.EntryDate) > 2017
       AND ii.ConsignorName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
       ii.ConsignorName,
       ii.ConsignorAddress,
       rc.CountryName
ORDER BY
       ii.ConsignorName ASC,
```

My proposed logic: using Soundex fuction in SQL, but soundex has limitations...

[image]

Source: http://www.basistech.com/whitepapers/the-name-matching-you-need-EN.pdf

But this method just only word on short text 4 to 5 words string...

Is there any other way to predict accurate data using SQL? One that performs pattern matching?

Another output will be like I want to check the trade of the trader

Comment: Probably not with SQL Server no. Sounds like something for a Machine learning tool. The route cause, however, seems to be that you don't have a table with your traders in, for users to select from. Instead you have them free type the value every time; so of course you will have anomalies. I think you need to really need to consider introducing some foreign key constraints and "lookup tables". You might well, eventually, fix the data you have but that doesn't stop it being in an awful state again in the future.

Comment: ok i appreciate your advice.. but what if i have a list of suppliers, i want to get the similar supplier names that are actually same but mistakenly wrongly typed by the user.\

Comment: My point still stands. That or get an actual person to fix the data and then implement good validation/constraints.

Comment: is there a way to get similar names after getting the list of list of misspelled names.

Comment: How would you suppose that SQL Server knows if a name is misspelled? It doesn't have a concept of "spelling". Again, this is why having a proper set up with foreign key constraints will (eventually) fix the problem. You, or maybe more specifically someone, will need to fix **every** piece of data you have so that it's correct, and then you can enforce the foreign key constraints on your table to the `Trader` table. While they're fixing it, you'll need to implement logic so that people don't input bad data till your data cleanse is complete.

Comment: SQL Server isn't responsible for the problem you're facing, nor can it fix it. The bad design is the reason, and someone (an actual person) will need to be responsible for fixing it (most likely manually).

Comment: Dear Larnu, you point is valid in my case but i am facing the issue now 

i have the just data and i need to write a sql query that generates a report that are nearly similar to one another using SQL any algorithm or any thing.... is there any way to predict pattern matching or similarity of the names that are already ambigue.

Comment: Like I said before SQL isn't the right language to try that. You'll be best with a machine learning language, like Python. But, like I said before, my point stands that you need to fix the data. Not doing so will just let the problem get worse and worse. It seems that your data is already in an unusable state; and unusable data is useless data. SQL is far better is literals, "is this the same value as this value?", "Does this value have these characters in it?", "Is this value greater than this value?". It doesn't have functionality such as "could this string be a misspelling of this string?"